# AndEngine force close on loading examples

Tags: android, andengine

I just downloaded andengine project with examples with extensions in eclipse. Most of the examples work just fine. However, those involving physics and the games(snake,racer,pong) get a force close message on my device. in the error log I get stackOverflow error that takes me to this piece of code:

```
public FontManager getFontManager() {
    return this.getFontManager();
}
```

Did anyone have this problem before? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just fix it with:

```
public FontManager getFontManager() {
    return this.mEngine.getFontManager();
}
```

This bug was reported in november on [AndEngine project site](http://code.google.com/p/andengine/issues/detail?id=60#c0). No commits since september there.

Comment: I posted a new question regarding another problem that occured. If you could help I'd be thankfull.

Answer (score 3):

Change `return this.getFontManager();` to `return this.mEngine.getFontManager();`